# style input tag

Tags: asp.net, css

ASP.Net has a tag called CheckboxList. The output of this tag looks like this:

```
<table class="checkbox">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="/*longdynamicstring1*/" type="checkbox" name="/*longdynamicstring2*/" />
        <label for="/*longdynamicstring1*/">Label Text</label>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to position the label and the input but I cannot find out how. Tried the following:

```
.checkbox input{
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

and

```
.checkbox input[type='checkbox']
{
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

but neither of them had any effect. Because it's ASP I cannot set a class for the input elements and I cannot reference the id because it's dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector works well, it's just that `padding` has no effect on the check box. Margin will work, for example:

```
.checkbox input {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

See it in action: http://jsbin.com/irari

In addition, take a look at the [`RepeatLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatlayout.aspx) property - it can make the generated HTML more CSS friendly.

Comment: Thank you! I usually try other properties to see that something really doesn't work but in this case somehow I forgot it.